# Php и mysql ошибка запроса к бд

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Ошибка: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

```
$sort = price desk;
$result = mysqli_query($link,'SELECT * FROM table_product WHERE Product_visible=1 ORDER BY '.$sort);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)
```

Вроде все правильно, Mysqli_erorr выводит  "", то есть  - ничего(

Comment: @Юра Сучко, у вас в коде именно так написано: $sort = price desk; ?

Comment: И в кавычки, наверное, надо заключить price desk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sort = "price desk";// кавычки это раз, и что реально поле через пробел???? или там подчеркивание есть???
$result = mysqli_query($link,'SELECT * FROM table_product WHERE Product_visible=1 ORDER BY '.$sort);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)
```